# Nothing happens when i try to change TextView value dynamically in a fragment

Tags: android

I tried everything on the internet but still couldn't update the value. but however i can update the progress bar value. i wonder why i can update progress but not the textview value

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ProgressBar prograss_bar;
        int prograss = 28;
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
        TextView prograss_perc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sale_prog_pres);
        prograss_perc.setText(String.valueOf(prograss));
        prograss_bar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.sales_prog);
        prograss_bar.setProgress(prograss);


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);


    }
```

I get empty value for the Textview but progress bar updates. what can i do?

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".tab1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sale_prog_pres"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/sales_prog"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/sales_prog"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/sales_prog"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sales_prog" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/sales_prog"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="247dp"
        android:layout_height="212dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.396" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rights"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Powered by Sinewavesoft "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If you hardcode the string inside the `TextView` e.g. `android:text="test123"`, are you seeing anything?

Comment: yes. when i hard code it it appears

Comment: do you have the id `sale_prog_pres` used anywhere else in the project?

Comment: Also can you change `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);` to just `return view;` ?

Comment: changing the return value did the trick! thanx :)

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems with your code.

First, make sure your text color is different from background color by adding `android:textColor="#FFF"`.

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/sale_prog_pres"
      android:layout_width="84dp"
      android:layout_height="29dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:background="@android:color/black"
      android:textColor="#FFF" 
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/sales_prog"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/sales_prog"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/sales_prog"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sales_prog" />
```

Second, change `onCreateView` method code to

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

      ProgressBar prograss_bar;
      int prograss = 28;
      TextView prograss_perc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sale_prog_pres);
      prograss_perc.setText(String.valueOf(prograss));
      prograss_bar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.sales_prog);
      prograss_bar.setProgress(prograss);

      // This line is IMPORTANT!!!
      return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code snippet you provided, you're setting the text value of TextView `prograss_perc` to the string value of the object itself. It should be:

```java
int progress = 28;
prograss_perc.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
```

Edit: The TextView is behind the ProgressBar. Use this instead.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".tab1">
    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/sales_prog"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="247dp"
            android:layout_height="212dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.396" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sale_prog_pres"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/sales_prog"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/sales_prog"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/sales_prog"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sales_prog" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rights"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Powered by Sinewavesoft "
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Oh silly me. well i changed it but still don't work. i added hard coded value still not working

Comment: Please, let's see the XML layout. @UthpalaBandara

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12UrMLT-rJhch2TnVRz0BOdwn6z7eZYkn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks but it would be better to edit your question and paste the XML there.

Comment: yeah sure :) can do

Comment: still no luck :